# If my son is attending a nursery school, do I need to provide a letter from the school to receive a Schengen visa?

Tags: schengen, paperwork, italy, minors

I am an Indian living in UK. I have a 3-year old son who is attending nursery.  I am planning for a trip to Italy and am applying for a Schengen visa from the  Italian Consulate in London.

[VFS](http://it.vfsglobal.co.uk/minors.html) requires that I provide:

> Recent (not older than 1 month) original school attendance letter duly signed by the school’s Headmaster and addressed to the Italian consulate; if the school letter is not signed, it should mention that the same letter is electronically generated and doesn’t require a signature

Does it is apply for nursery-going children too? Do I need to specify the travel dates too in the letter?

Comment: Its **point 8** on tab "Documents Required" on [VFS](http://it.vfsglobal.co.uk/minors.html)
_Recent (not older than 1 month) original school attendance letter duly signed by the school’s Headmaster and addressed to the Italian consulate_

Comment: My wife will also be accompanying the trip.

Comment: Whether or not such a letter is strictly required for a 3-year-old in nursery school, it seems like it wouldn't be particularly difficult to type up such a letter yourself and ask someone at the school office to sign it for you. And then you wouldn't have to worry about the application being rejected for this reason.

Comment: Did you try emailing the VFS? It seems like this is a requirement for minors who apply on their own, rather than with their parents

Comment: We asked nursery and they gave it the next day without any issues. I think they already have some standard letters and didn't asked us the dates. But Italian Vfs didn't take it when I presented it to them saying it's ok for young children.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No particular pieces of documentation is *mandatory* when applying for a Schengen visa (except for the application form itself and the travel document the visa is to be issued in) -- consulates are required to review *whatever is submitted* and decide whether it convinces them the applicant satisfies the (broad and fuzzy) conditions.

(Also, remember that VFS is just a glorified courier service -- they don't decide applications and can't *require* anything; but they will reproduce *advice* from the consulates about which documentation they usually like to see).

For children *of school age* it makes sense to ask whether the child's school has been consulted in the travel plan. In contrast to nurseries, schools run coherent programs of learning where it will harm a child's *further* progress suddenly to miss one or more weeks -- so if parents were willing to go on a family trip without coordinating with the school, a suspicion would arise that they're not *planning* to return the child to that school, but instead try to immigrate illegally as an entire family.

But there's no such thing as "missing a week (or a month) of kindergarten" and having to make up for it later. So a letter from a nursery school would not actually help document anything relevant for a visa decision.

On the other hand, it it hard to imagine it would *hurt* -- consulates must be used to cautious applicants following the document list slavishly even where it doesn't make sense.

Comment: It's worth noting that people of any nationality resident in UK have extremely high chances of obtaining a Schengen visa, since there's very little incentive for them to immigrate illegally.

Comment: Calling Vfs never helped me. They just read the same things there on website. One thing which I have realized in my last 2 successful applications that they are slightly relaxed with to whom it is addressed, so instead of addressing to a particular embassy "to whom it may concern" worked for me.